# Is there a name for this matrix operation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Transforming a matrix by copying each element up to a certain given length ($k$) and then starting on the next row with the second element, and row after that with the third, etc. So each row is shifted by one more. For example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\2 & 3 & 4\\3 & 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}
$$

With a parameter $k=3$ or

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\2 & 3 & 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}
$$

With a parameter $k=4$.

Comment: If such operation is useful, it certainly has a name. And conversely.

Comment: Thinking to a fixed length window (length = 3 or 2 in your example) : you are sliding this window on the message "1 2 3 4 5" and you gather the results in a new matrix : thus it has something common with 
 discrete **convolution** but I don't see any "closed form" matrix expression that can render this operation...

Comment: I would call the 1st operation [Hankelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation looks a little too particular to me to have a (well known) name.

The resulting matrix is like a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) (except that it's constant along the anti-diagonals), could be regarded as some sort of "toeplitzation" (ugh)...

For example, the second example in Matlab/Octave:

```
>> fliplr(toeplitz([4,5],[4,3,2,1]))
ans =

   1   2   3   4
   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: Thanks! This opened up some good things for me to look into. From Toeplitz I found [Hankel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html#scipy.linalg.hankel) which seems like I can use to do at least something close to what I need.

Comment: If you are looking for ways to do this in Python, you may also be interested in [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).